# Enter character instead int C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a code that tally when an integer data type or character is entered.

```
    int numero,
        countInteger   = 0;
        countCharacter = 0;

    while ( 1 ) {

          try {

             cin  >> numero;
             cout << numero;
             throw   numero;

          } catch (...) {

             countCharacter++;
             cout << "Error";

          }
   }
```

If I entered Integer, counter in "countInteger" (but not show it in the code). If I enter a character, it is aa exception and recorded in "countCharacter".

But when I run the code generates an infinite loop and does not allow me to re-enter again. They could help me please. Guide me, you may have a bad concept.

Comment: The infinite loop is due to the while condition.

Comment: there is no way that the program can exit the loop.

Comment: I know. But I think you focus more on the logic of the code. I know that this creates an infinite loop but it will put an exit condition.It does not allow me to reread a new number

Comment: I want a sample of 100 keyboard input, tell me how many times a number is entered and how many times a character is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to read an integer, and you give something that's not an integer as input, there are two things happening: The first is that the stream gets its `failbit` set, the second things that happens is that the input is not extracted. So next iteration you read the same input again, and again and again...

I suggest another tactic: Read as a character, then see if it is a [digit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), an [alphabetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) character, or something else completely. Optionally, if you need the actual full number, read as a string, and try to [convert to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

---

A clarification: Input using `std::cin` is buffered. When you use the input operator `>>` then `std::cin` extracts characters from the buffer. If you try to read a number, but the first character in the buffer is not a digit, then the input operator will fail, and leave the character in the buffer.

Simple (hopefully) example:

Lets say you have this code

```
int number;
std::cin >> number;
std::cin >> number;
std::cin >> number;
```

As input for that part of the code, you enter

```
123abc
```

The first input will read `123` from the input, and stop at the letter, leaving the input as

```
abc
```

Now we come to the second input, and the code will see that the first character is not a digit, so it will set the `failbit` in the stream and leave the input as is:

```
abc
```

Then with the third input, the exact same thing as in the second happen.

Now imagine this was in a loop instead, the input operator `>>` will iteration after iteration see the non-digit input an promptly return, effectively giving you an infinite loop.

---

Now for a clarification of my suggestion... Depending on the goals and requirements of the program, you can instead read into a *character* and use [the character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) to see what types you have.

Something like

```
int countDigit     = 0;
int countCharacter = 0;
char ch;

while (std::cin >> ch)
{
    if (std::isdigit(ch))
        ++countDigit;
    else if (std::isalpha(ch))
        ++countCharacter;
    else
    {
        // Not a digit or an alphabetic character
        // I.e. newlines, spaces, control characters, etc.
    }
}
```

Finally a note about using exceptions for this: Most people would consider it bad. Exceptions are for *exceptions*, exceptional cases, not as part of the normal flow of the program. Throwing an exception is expensive and disrupts the normal flow. Only use them for exceptional things, like errors.

Comment: It was a mistake not to put my full code. I just wanted to focus more on the fact that did not allow me to return again to enter a number as an infinite loop (I know this is obvious from the while (1) but that would put an exit condition, when entering a character is generated it will be the exception and starts an infinite loop). It could be more explicit in the proposal if not too much trouble

Comment: Thanks Joachim Pileborg!